# webpage elements not responsive to size change

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, responsive-design

[image: my screen]

[image: friends screen]

so I am working on a project with a friend. He sent me the html css and js code to check and make changes on my pc. When I opened it on my laptop the alignment of tha login box as well as the text is out. I have been trying to fix this since a while but cant figure out. Also when I restore down my browser all the things get jumbled up. I know it has do to with responsiveness but I cant figure it out.

this is the html code for login box:

```
<svg class="Path_2_k" viewBox="0 0 443.746 644">
    <linearGradient id="Path_2_k" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0.533" x2="0.5" y1="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#e3e2e2" stop-opacity="0.341"></stop>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#beb7df" stop-opacity="0.341"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#Path_2_k)" stroke="rgba(112,112,112,1)" stroke-width="1px" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="4" shape-rendering="auto" id="Path_2_k" d="M 0 0 L 443.7462158203125 0 L 443.7462158203125 644 L 0 644 L 0 0 Z">
    </path>
    </svg>
```

And this is the css code for it

```
.Path_2_k {
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  width: 410px;
  height: 450px;
  left: 800px;
  top: 130px;
  transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

this is the html code for the text

```
<div id="CUTTING_EDGE__SOLUTION__to_all">
                    <span></span><span style="position:relative;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;font-size:40px;">CUTTING-EDGE <br/>SOLUTION </span><br><span>to all your </span><br><span style="position:relative;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;font-size:40px;">HR </span><br><span>needs</span>
</div>
```

and this is the css code for the text

```
#CUTTING_EDGE__SOLUTION__to_all {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Book Antiqua;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(51,129,94,1);
}
```

[link to css code](https://www.codepile.net/pile/LNADvBdK)
[link to html code](https://www.codepile.net/pile/VAmRk2zg)

```css
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ FONT ]*/

@font-face {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  src: url('../fonts/poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf'); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Poppins-Bold;
  src: url('../fonts/poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf'); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Poppins-Medium;
  src: url('../fonts/poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf'); 
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
  src: url('../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'); 
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ RESTYLE TAG ]*/

* {
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0px; 
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
 height: 100%;
 font-family: Poppins-Regular, sans-serif;
  /*overflow: scroll;*/
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
a {
 font-family: Poppins-Regular;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.7;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0px;
 transition: all 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
}

a:focus {
 outline: none !important;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
  color: #57b846;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
 margin: 0px;
}

p {
 font-family: Poppins-Regular;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.7;
 color: #666666;
 margin: 0px;
}

ul, li {
 margin: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}


/*---------------------------------------------*/
input {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
}

textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #999999; }
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #999999; }
input::-moz-placeholder { color: #999999; }
input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #999999; }

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #999999; }
textarea:-moz-placeholder { color: #999999; }
textarea::-moz-placeholder { color: #999999; }
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #999999; }

/*---------------------------------------------*/
button {
 outline: none !important;
 border: none;
 background: transparent;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

iframe {
 border: none !important;
}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Utility ]*/
.txt1 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #999999;
}

.txt2 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #666666;
}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ login ]*/

.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-login100 {
  width: 100%;  
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  /*overflow: scroll;*/
  background: #9053c7;
  background: linear-gradient(224.5deg, rgba(29,157,210,1) 0%, rgba(1,154,66,1) 100%);
}

.wrap-login100 {
  width: 960px;
  background: #83c6b5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 100px 130px 120px 95px;
}

/*.wrap-login200 {
  width: 300px;
  background: #83c6b5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 100px 130px 120px 95px;
}*/

#CUTTING_EDGE__SOLUTION__to_all {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Book Antiqua;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(51,129,94,1);
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[  ]*/
/*.login100-pic {
  width: 400px;
}

.login100-pic img {
  max-width: 100%;
}*/

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[  ]*/
.login100-form {
  width: 290px;
}

.login100-form-title {
  font-family: Poppins-Bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;

  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}


/*---------------------------------------------*/
.wrap-input100 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input100 {
  font-family: Poppins-Medium;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #666666;

  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0 30px 0 68px;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Focus ]*/
.focus-input100 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 25px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: rgba(87,184,70, 0.8);
}

.input100:focus + .focus-input100 {
  -webkit-animation: anim-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: anim-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-shadow {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px 25px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-shadow {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px 25px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.Path_2_k {
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  width: 410px;
  height: 450px;
  left: 800px;
  top: 130px;
  transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}

.symbol-input100 {
  font-size: 15px;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 25px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 35px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #666666;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.input100:focus + .focus-input100 + .symbol-input100 {
  color: #57b846;
  padding-left: 28px;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Button ]*/
.container-login100-form-btn {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.login100-form-btn {
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #57b846;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 25px;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.login100-form-btn:hover {
  background: #333333;
}



/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Responsive ]*/



@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .wrap-login100 {
    padding: 177px 90px 33px 85px;
  }

  .login100-pic {
    width: 35%;
  }

  .login100-form {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrap-login100 {
    padding: 100px 80px 33px 80px;
  }

  .login100-pic {
    display: none;
  }

  .login100-form {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .wrap-login100 {
    padding: 100px 15px 33px 15px;
  }
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Alert validate ]*/

.validate-input {
  position: relative;
}

.alert-validate::before {
  content: attr(data-validate);
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #c80000;
  border-radius: 13px;
  padding: 4px 25px 4px 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;

  font-family: Poppins-Medium;
  color: #c80000;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: left;

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

.alert-validate::after {
  content: "\f06a";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: #c80000;
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 13px;
}

.alert-validate:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .alert-validate::before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Login V1</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================--> 
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="limiter">
  <div class="container-login100">
   <div class="wrap-login100">
    <img src="pngformat.png" style="width:100%;max-width:400px;max-height: 250px; position: relative; bottom:100px;right:150px;">
    <div id="CUTTING_EDGE__SOLUTION__to_all">
     <span></span><span style="position:relative;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;font-size:40px;">CUTTING-EDGE <br/>SOLUTION </span><br><span>to all your </span><br><span style="position:relative;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;font-size:40px;">HR </span><br><span>needs</span>
    </div>
    <svg class="Path_2_k" viewBox="0 0 443.746 644">
      <linearGradient id="Path_2_k" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0.533" x2="0.5" y1="0" y2="1">
       <stop offset="0" stop-color="#e3e2e2" stop-opacity="0.341"></stop>
       <stop offset="1" stop-color="#beb7df" stop-opacity="0.341"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <path fill="url(#Path_2_k)" stroke="rgba(112,112,112,1)" stroke-width="1px" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="4" shape-rendering="auto" id="Path_2_k" d="M 0 0 L 443.7462158203125 0 L 443.7462158203125 644 L 0 644 L 0 0 Z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    <form class="login100-form validate-form">
     <span class="login100-form-title">
      Login
     </span>

     <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
      <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      <span class="symbol-input100">
       <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
     </div>

     <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
      <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      <span class="symbol-input100">
       <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
     </div>
     
     <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
      <button class="login100-form-btn">
       Login
      </button>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need see example of full struct-er of page to tell you what is effected on box

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/VAmRk2zg

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/LNADvBdK

Answer (score 0):

Try this example of CSS and compere with your code to find what happen and read this [document](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp) for fix problem.

```
.Path_2_k {
filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.161));
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
width: 25%; /* edit this one */
height: 92%; /* edit this one */
left: 51%; /* edit this one */
top: 15%; /* edit this one */
transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```